# What type is the function input to String.withCString()?

Tags: swift

I'm using the function `String.withCString()` as follows:

```
let s = "Hey!"
let c = s.withCString {
    strlen($0)
}
println(c)
```

However, if I add a second line to the withCString closure, I get an error

```
let s = "Hey!"
let c = s.withCString {
    println("test")
    strlen($0)
}
println(c)
```

The error is: "Cannot convert the expression's type '(($T4) -> $T3) -> (($T4) -> $T3) -> $T3' to type 'Result'.

Looking at the declaration for `withCString` it says:

```
func withCString<Result>(f: (UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> Result) -> Result
```

Which I have been interpreting as saying that the `f` parameter will be a function that takes an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` as input and returns some type as a result. This is what my second example is doing. What's wrong with the second example block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should

```
let s = "Hey!"
let c = s.withCString { (cstr) -> UInt in
    println("test")
    return strlen(cstr)
}
println(c)
```

This declaration:

```
func withCString<Result>(f: (UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> Result) -> Result
```

means return type of `withCString` is return type of the parameter `f`.

Your first example, :

```
let c = s.withCString {
    strlen($0)
}
```

The closure has only one expression, this causes ["Implicit Return"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_157), and the compiler can determine the return type of it as `UInt`.

The second one has two statements. then you have to declare the return type and `return` explicitly.

Comment: The closure type declaration, `(cstr) -> UInt in` is required to make this work. Do you know why that would be the case? I would expect that `s.withCString { println("test"); return strlen($0) }` would work just as well as your example code.

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't assume the return type unless it's single-expression closure. I think, it's by language design.